# How to add folder sharing or sharing options to the File manager context menu?

Tags: release-hera, settings, pantheon-files, applications, networking

I configured the samba service correctly and I can see the share folder from a windows computer but when I want to share the folder downloads, documents or any other from my personal folder I can not, I deploy context menu and normally you would see in ubuntu sharing options but in elementary I do not find such an option, what package would be missing to add the function to this file manager?
Also I would like to know which is the web page of the file manager developer as it doesn't give much information in the app store, the name of the file manager is very generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

You have to add this ppa on your repositories : http://ppa.launchpad.net/yunnxx/elementary/ubuntu/

The elementary-shared-folder is in this repository :

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install elementary-shared-folder

Best regards

Comment: Excellent this is the answer and the solution to the question, I added the repository, updated and installed and it works very well, thank you very much. On the other hand there is very little information on how to implement this resource considering that you have to add the repository and does not come at least as an option in Synaptic, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

#### Sharing Options in Files

I don't believe this is possible directly from Files.

#### Alternatives

The configuration files for your samba server can be modified with a text editor or graphically with the [system-config-samba](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/system-config-samba) utility or [GNOME Files](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Files), packaged as `nautilus`, with the [nautilus-share](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nautilus-share) plugin as you mentioned.
The [Ubuntu Wiki's Samba Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide) serves as a good reference for the various methods of configuring a samba server.

It sounds like you're used to using GNOME Files, so I've included the command to install it with the share plugin here.

```
sudo apt -y install nautilus nautilus-share
```

#### Files Plugins

Plugins for Files can be found with the following command via apt, but this only shows a Dropbox plugin at the moment.

```
sudo apt search pantheon-files-plugin-
```

#### Files Website

The File's GitHub repository can be found [here](https://github.com/elementary/files).

Comment: Thanks for the help jwillikers, I did not find pantheon-share in Synaptic. I appreciate the suggestion to choose nautilus as a file manager but I stayed with the nemo manager because it is better in terms of appearance. On the other hand I was in the same situation as with pantheon-files which did not have the same package that is missing to pantheon but I happened to extract the .deb package of this feature from Linux Mint, so I gave myself the task of installing nemo as a file manager and add the sharing with nemo-share.

Comment: This way I was able to share files from the contextual menu, maybe someone more experienced would have done this process differently. Anyway thank you very much for the help because from this publication and reading your comment I was able to develop this exercise through the information you provided me, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Searching on Synaptic package Manager, I have found 'elementary-shared-folder'. No need to install nautilus IMHO.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help but in Synaptic you can't find the feature you mention, greetings.